# What is maximum number of routes that can be sent in one lsa update packet

Tags: ospf

What is maximum number of routes that can be sent in one lsa update packet.I know the lsa update is send in response to lsa request. But there would be some number right.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The RFC (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2328) does not list a maximum number of routes for Update LSA. (that I've found...)

Section A.1 (page 185) states that the maximum size for an OSPF packet is the maximum IP packet size of 65,535 bytes, and recommends that larger packets (it specifically mentions Update packets) be broken down into several smaller OSPF packets to avoid IP fragmentation.

Answer (score -3):

There is no as such limits for carrying LSA size.

Comment: Welcome to the community, and thank you for contributing.  However, could I ask that you in some way back up your statement with some reasoning and/or provide references that support your statement?  This would make it a much better answer and more useful both to the OP and to future community members that view this question and answer.

Comment: There has to be some limit and I imagine that the MTU be deciding factor how much can be crammed into one LSA.

Comment: MTU is not a protocol-specific limit...